# How to Permit/Deny Traffic based on Domain Name (FQDN) rather than ip address in AZURE?

Tags: firewall, azure, access-control-list

I can add inbound/outbound rules in azure network security group for IP address , but how can i make that for domain name (URL) ?

Comment: Why this question is closed? This is pretty much hot question in multi-cloud setups.

Answer (score 5):

For the reasons below:

By design:  **Many security systems simply don't support creating ACL's using a FQDN.** And you're only allowed to create ACL's with IP-address (range) information.

> **Warning:** Any systems that do support ACL's containing a FQDN will, on closer inspection,  most likely not actually provide the  level of security, flexibility and/or behaviour that you intuitively expect.

---

In general the problem with using a FQDN in ACL's is rooted in the fundamental thruth:

> Your (security) **systems only see IP-addresses** as the sources and destinations of network traffic.

To use a FQDN your security system either needs  to **perform a reverse DNS lookup** whenever traffic containing a new and unknown ip-address arrives to determine if that particular IP-address resolves to a FQDN in your access control lists, or **the FQDN needs to be resolved to IP-addresses before the access policy gets applied**.

---

### Live reverse DNS lookups

The problem with live reverse lookups , in addition to the fact that it can be **slow**, is that the owner of an IP-address can set *any hostname name they want on a reverse DNS record*, including one from domains that they don't own, notably your own domain... So that is both slow, unreliable and insecure.

<sub>For example a standard trick for penetration testers/attackers is to set their own PTR record to `something.contoso.com.` when they're evaluating the security for Contoso. Then they'll be included in any a security policy that trusts  `*.contoso.com` ...</sub>

---

### Resolve FQDN's

Alternatively systems could (automatically) translate the supplied FQDN to an IP-address in the background/management tooling and effectively apply your policies to the IP-addresses the FQDN's resolve to.   That will prevent the slow, unreliable and insecure reverse lookups, but that **results in a different set of problems**:

- many systems don't show which IP-addresses the FQFN resolved to when applying the rule set.
- systems that do show the IP-addresses often don't show the original FQDN  anymore.
  <sub>*Or when they do show a FQDN they'll often show the result of a reverse DNS lookup on the IP-addresses and you'll see that often a PTR doesn't align with the initial forward DNS record, confusion guaranteed.*</sub>
- the IP-address(es) associated with a FQDN can be changed at any time by the owner of the domain and how and when will the new IP-address replace the old one in your policies?
  <sub>*Many systems **resolve the FQDN only once** and will from then on "forever" use the resolved IP-address(es). I don't know any system that implements adhering to for example the TTL of the DNS record or any other method to regularly check if the FQDN still resolves to the same IP-addresses and if changed will update the IP's used in the effective ACL.*</sub>
- a FQDN can even resolve to multiple IP-addresses. Both IPv4 and IPv6 and multiple of each.
  <sub>*Many systems require(d) separate rules for IPv4 and IPv6* and/or don't support round-robin DNS records in an expected/consistent manner.</sub>
- a FQDN may resolve to different (ranges of) IP-addresses (anycast / geo DNS) depending on your client IP-address doing the resolving, so a policy based on the FQDN can't possibly match all actual IP-addresses...

Comment: and what's the solution, if there is just a FQDN, not a static public IP ?

Comment: You resolve the FQDN to an IP-address manually with all the associated problems / risks mentioned above.

Answer (score 2):

Currently, it is not possible.

Single IP address (example: 10.10.10.10), IP subnet (example: 192.168.1.0/24), or * (for all addresses) are supported. Please refer to this [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-nsg).

If you really need this, you could give a [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217313-networking) to Azure Network Team.

Note: Currently, you could add your domain's IP to NSG instead of domain name.